# Como descargo a mi maquina local el codigo de un proyecto de digital ocean

Tags: digitalocean

Hola estoy en un proyecto en el cual se encuentra vigente en Digital Ocean y tengo el acceso como tal, y veo que el aplicativo que esta allí se encuentra mucho mas estable y mas actualizado de el repositorio que me brindaron de GitLab quisiera saber como podria descargar el codigo de lo que esta actualmente en la nube a mi maquina local y poder actualizar unas tareas que ya he realizado para nuevo subirlas a Digital Ocean.

Comment: Si nos muestras lo que estás intentando usar en vez de suponer que lo sabemos, opsiblemente recibas respuesta más rápido

Comment: Esta herramienta podría ahorrarte algo de tiempo mientras aprendes los comandos https://desktop.github.com/ Cuando agregues un repositorio, utiliza URL en lugar de Github o Github Enterprise. Saludos.